# Locale based validation

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, hibernate-validator

My project have two main requirements

1) Different set of rules applied to same object at insertion and while updating it.

2) Different validation rules based on locale.

**In ADDRESS object STATE field requires different validation rules
For USA: STATE cannot be NULL.
For everywhere else it can be NULL.**

For first requirement i am already using GROUPS.
Is there a way to achieve second requirements.

I am using:
Hibernate Validator 4.0.1 GA
Hibernate 5.2.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question got answered on the [Hibernate Validator forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1004845). Best way to go is a class-level constraint or a Validator instance per Locale. I really wouldn't recommend the latter, but it's a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

I would make the country (`Locale` based or not is up to you) part of the `Address` and use a custom [class-level constraint](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/BeanValidationSneakPeekPartIICustomConstraints#H-ClasslevelConstraints) to do the validation.

Comment: Thanks Pascal. But isn't there any kind of support in the framework for localized validations. Like different validation xml files for each region ( mechanism similar to language properties files i.e messages.properties , messages_fr.properties etc ). Or anything like multiple group options ( a group with in a group or something of this sort ).